# Import commonJS module and emit SystemJS bundle

Tags: typescript

I have a project written in Typescript which outputs a SystemJS bundle using `module:'system'` and `outFile`. I would like to pull in some NPM-installed CJS modules. Is it possible to import them and have them emitted into the bundle as SystemJS modules? There doesn't seem to be, but I can't find a definitive answer on this.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to bundle the packages your depending on on the outFile?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to be able to `npm install` packages, import them in the project code, and build a single bundle.

Answer (score 0):

By default TypeScript won't bundle all dependencies in a single file. It will only bundle your files.

If you want to bundle the dependencies as well, you should check the [TsProject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsproject) package.

Comment: If I pass a relative path to `import foo = require('../node_modules/bar')`, it will include it in the bundle, but it does not register it as a systemJS module as it does with my other project imports.

So it seems that if I use `require('bar')` and it automatically resolves the node_modules folder, it doesn't emit the dependency. If I give it a relative path, it does emit, but ignores the module type set in the compiler options.

Comment: Is this behavior intentional? Are there any recommended workflows that don't require maintaining a separate config to handle 3rd party deps? Ideally I would love to simply import regardless of whether the code lives in my project src or under `node_modules`, and have the compiler emit a single bundle with all deps resolved. Installing libs via NPM then having to maintain config to load them in order to satisfy dependencies for a separate project bundle is a bit of a pain and error prone.

Comment: This article http://www.jbrantly.com/es6-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack/ has a good explanation on the subject

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't think it answers the question though. It explains different syntax for importing ES5 CJS libs, but I already know that. Unless I'm missing something, there is no explanation regarding importing CJS then emitting it in a single SystemJS bundle.